# How to set git remote heroku?

Tags: heroku, github

When I'm trying to use the command `heroku git:remote -a sleepy-inlet-36834`
,I got `set git remote heroku to https://git.heroku.com/sleepy-inlet-36834.git` in terminal. Then I tried to set the git remote heroku like this.

```
heroku git:remote -a https://git.heroku.com/sleepy-inlet-36834.git.
```

That time I got an error message something like this.

```
 ▸    The requested API endpoint was not found. Are you using the right HTTP
 ▸    verb (i.e. `GET` vs. `POST`), and did you specify your intended version
 ▸    with the `Accept` header?
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: please help me with an answer..

Answer (score 9):

you could add the remote the git way:

```
git remote add heroku https://git.heroku.com/sleepy-inlet-36834.git.
```

Comment: You can run: 'git remote rm heroku' and try agian but that also may mean you have already set the git remote

Comment: I tried again after run "git remote rm heroku" and push the codes using "git push heroku master". I got an error "! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/sleepy-inlet-36834.git'  "

Answer (score 2):

```
git remote rm heroku
```

Removes previous heroku

```
git remote add heroku https://example-example.git
```

Sets git remote heroku to `https://example-example.git`